# How to save rcParam settings to file to use it in another script

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have different python scripts for generating different plots. I have defined a function for changing rcParams. As shown below.

Now this function is defined in a file. I want to use this saved file of rcparam's in other python scripts.

So how should I save this rcparam to file what should be the extension and how to call this customized rcParam's to other python scripts.

```
def customizer():
    figure = {
        'figsize'   : 6.4, 4.8   ## figure size in inches
        'dpi'       : 100        ## figure dots per inch
    }
    axes = {
        'titlesize' : 'large'    ## fontsize of the axes title
        }

    ticks = {
        'labelsize' : 12         ## fontsize of the tick labels
    }

    font = {'family' : 'sans-serif',
            #'weight' : 'bold',
            'size'   : 12}

    plt.rc('font', **font)        # controls default text sizes
    plt.rc('axes', **axes)        # fontsize of the axes title
    plt.rc('xtick', **ticks)      # fontsize of the tick labels
    plt.rc('ytick', **ticks)      # fontsize of the tick labels
```

Comment: In python every file is a module. So you can just import the file and call the function from it. But of course setting rcParams is usually done by creating a matplotlib style file instead. I'd recommend reading [the customizing tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: So which is better way of customizing settings, creating style or matplotlibrc file. Both seem to be same. what is the difference between them

Comment: Yes, both are the same. Not sure what the question is.

Comment: Does one method have advantage or disadvantage over the other.

Comment: Which methods are we talking about here? (In any case, just use the one you like more)